# In Java, get all weekend dates in a given month

Tags: java, date, weekend

I need to find all the weekend dates for a given month and a given year.

Eg: For 01(month), 2010(year), the output should be :  2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31,  all weekend dates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a rough version with comments describing the steps:

```
// create a Calendar for the 1st of the required month
int year = 2010;
int month = Calendar.JANUARY;
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
do {
    // get the day of the week for the current day
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // check if it is a Saturday or Sunday
    if (day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        // print the day - but you could add them to a list or whatever
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    // advance to the next day
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}  while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month);
// stop when we reach the start of the next month
```

Comment: sample is not working properly it gives output :2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30, but for jan 2010 the week end list are2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31 . please tell me where is the pro

Comment: There was a bug in the `while` condition where the last day of the month was being missed. I have fixed it now.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: This code is just flat out wrong in many locales; not all locales consider 'Saturday and Sunday' the weekend days!

Answer (score 14):

## java.time

You can use the [Java 8 stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Here an [`IntStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) from `1` to the number of days in the given month is generated. This stream is  mapped to a stream of [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) in the given month then filtered to keep Saturday's and Sunday's.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Stackoverflow{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int year    = 2010;
        Month month = Month.JANUARY;

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1,YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth())
                 .mapToObj(day -> LocalDate.of(year, month, day))
                 .filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ||
                                 date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
                 .forEach(date -> System.out.print(date.getDayOfMonth() + " "));
    }
}
```

We find the same result as the first answer (2 3 9 10 16 17 23 24 30 31).

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Lokni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845918/642706) appears to be correct, with bonus points for using Streams.

## `EnumSet`

My suggestion for improvement: [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). This class is an extremely efficient implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Represented internally as bit vectors, they are fast to execute and taking very little memory.

Using an `EnumSet` enables you to [soft-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding) the definition of the weekend by passing in a `Set<DayOfWeek>`.

```
Set<DayOfWeek> dows = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
```

Demo using the old-fashioned syntax without Streams. You could adapt [Lokni’s answer’s code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845918/642706) to use an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) in a similar manner.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY ) ;
int initialCapacity = ( ( ym.lengthOfMonth() / 7 ) + 1 ) * dows.size() ;  // Maximum possible weeks * number of days per week.
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>(  initialCapacity  );
for (int dayOfMonth = 1;  dayOfMonth <= ym.lengthOfMonth() ;  dayOfMonth ++) {
    LocalDate ld =  ym.atDay( dayOfMonth ) ;
    DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
    if( dows.contains( dow ) ) {  
        // Is this date *is* one of the days we care about, collect it.
        dates.add( ld );
    }
}
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

You can also make use of the [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html?is-external=true) interface which provides for classes that manipulate date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural `s`) provides several handy implementations.

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project provides classes working with java.time. This includes a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation, [`Temporals.nextWorkingDay()`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay--).

You can write your own implementation to do the opposite, a `nextWeekendDay` temporal adjuster.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try like this:

```
int year=2016;
int month=10;
calendar.set(year, 10- 1, 1);
int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
ArrayList<Date> sundays = new ArrayList<Date>();>

for (int d = 1;  d <= daysInMonth;  d++) {
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
      int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
      if (dayOfWeek==Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, d);
            sundays.add(calendar.getTime());
      }
}
```

Comment: FYI, these notoriously troublesome and confusing old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid the old classes.

Comment: Still relevant for Android developers.