# java calendar weekend of current week

Tags: java, calendar, weekend

Java using calendar i want to get date of current weekend, any quick idea

Comment: I assume you mean in the western Calendar?  The weekend is Thursday/Friday, or only Sunday in some places.

Comment: Current means coming? or the one just passed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java example to get all weekend dates in a given month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272454/java-example-to-get-all-weekend-dates-in-a-given-month)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
c.getTime(); // => Date of this coming Saturday.
```

Comment: I love it, because here we don't care what day it is today. +1

Comment: Now outdated. The java.time classes supplant the troublesome old `Calendar` class seen here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();;
currDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SATURDAY - currDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) ));
System.out.println("weekend date is in the " + curreDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: I love the way you are coming from. And the use of all `DAY_OF_XXXXX`. Awesome!! +1

Comment: Now outdated. The java.time classes supplant the troublesome old `Calendar` class seen here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String dayNames[]={"lundi","mardi","mercredi","jeudi","vendredi","samedi","dimanche"};
        String nomthNames[]={"janvier","février","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","Août","septembre","octobre","novembre","decembre"};
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dayName = dayNames[date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];
        String dayMonth = nomthNames[date.get(Calendar.MONTH)];

        lblBonjour.setText("<html><b>Bonjour, "+new Functions().getNomPrenom(myID)+"</b><br>"+
                "Ajourd'hui "+dayName+" "+date.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+dayMonth+" "+date.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"<br>"+
                "Heure locale: "+date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+date.get(Calendar.MINUTE) );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joda Time**

```
new DateTime().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY)
```

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its team advises magrating to the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7, see the ThreeTen-Backport project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will give both the start and end of week days.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, cal.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
int weekStart = cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,weekStart);
Date WeekStartDate=cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,weekStart+7);
Date WeekEndDate=cal.getTime(
```

Comment: Now outdated. The java.time classes supplant the troublesome old Calendar class seen here.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )                      // Today, in specific time zone.
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) )  // Next Saturday, or today if already Saturday.
         .plusDays( 1 )                                               // Sunday
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome poorly-designed `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

### Current date

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### Moving to the next weekend

You can adjust from one date to another using an implementation of the [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface. Some handy implementations are provided in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class, such as [`nextOrSame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-). Specify a day-of-week using a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) object. Note that a `DayOfWeek` is an actual object rather than a mere number or string, providing [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and ensuring valid values.

```
LocalDate saturday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) ) ;
LocalDate sunday = saturday.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

If you want to the same or *previous* weekend, call the [`previousOrSame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) adjuster.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).