# Removing weekends in a vector filled with Dates

Tags: java

I have a vector that is created by retrieving data from a database
It is filled with information that includes Date, Time, Volume ect... 
I need to create a spreadsheet from these values however I need to Remove values where
the date is on a weekend(and specific holidays if possible) but more importantly the weekends
If anyone knows of a function that is able to do this that would be great Thanks.

Comment: This question would be improved by adding some sample code and an example of the vector data.

Comment: Can you modify the SQL used to retrieve the data to exclude the weekends?

Comment: `java.util.Date`  or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272454/java-example-to-get-all-weekend-dates-in-a-given-month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `Date` object in Java, then you can use the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object to do this.

Get an instance of the Calendar, then call get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK).  If the value is Saturday or Sunday, remove it from your `Collection`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDateObject);
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    //remove this Date
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the timestamp of the Date, you could use a GregorianCalendar.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setFirstDayOfWeek(int)

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) // Would be Calendar.SUNDAY or something;
```