# How to get all weekend between two specific day of month using java8 time API?

Tags: java, date, time, java-time, weekday

I want to get all weekend between two specific day of month (e.g. from 2018-10-26 to 2018-11-27) using java8 time api. How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `Stream.iterate(LocalDate.parse("2018-10-26"), LocalDate.parse("2018-11-27")::isAfter, Duration.ofDays(1)::addTo).filter(this::isWeekday)`

Comment: Duplicate of [*In Java, get all weekend dates in a given month*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3272454/642706)

Comment: **Search Stack Overflow** thoroughly before posting. Assume any basic date-time Question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3):

Try this function, it will get all Saturday and Sunday from your Time

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 26);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 27);
while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
    if (startDate.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) || startDate.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
        System.out.println(startDate + ":" + startDate.getDayOfWeek());
    }
    startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Please always give explanation to your answer even when you provide codes.

Comment: @holydragon this code is self-explanatory, no explanation needed here

Comment: For a twist on this Answer, you could use [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)) to produce a `Stream<LocalDate>` to work with.