# is there any easy way to get number of weekend in a month in java

Tags: java, date, weekend

I want to find number of weekend (here weekend may be one or more day) from a particular month of particular date. Like if number of weekend is 2 i.e. saturday and sunday than how to calculate total number of weekend from  a date like 2019-11-15 in java.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more in detail? What if the first day of a month is a Sunday, does that count as weekend number one for that month?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272454/in-java-get-all-weekend-dates-in-a-given-month

Comment: You are expected to do research prior asking a question. It also works much better to include your own efforts, instead of simply dumping your requirements here, looking to others to do all the heavy lifting on your behalf.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica why would anyone upvote this question? It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @xenteros Honestly, I don't know. Probably the person writing the code-only answer helped with that, to get the OP to upvote levels. I for sure didn't upvote.

Comment: You will want to look into `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Under the linked original question I recommend the [answer by Ortomala Lokni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845918/5772882) and [by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925397/5772882).

Answer (score -1):

```
public int weekendCount(int year, int month) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i= 1; i<= daysInMonth; i++) {
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, i);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Try this.

year -2019, month -11 
output=9

Comment: java.util.Calendar is so 1999.

Comment: we are setting year - calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);